# How to configure local kubectl to remote access to cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, apply, kubectl

We have setup with two Kubernetes VMs on Ubuntu Server, a master and a worker.  The cluster appears healthy, I'm still learning my way around.  I know you can build an image and push it to docker hub and then pull that image down from the Kubernetes server.

My trouble is everything I'm learning says you use a .yaml file to create the deployment.  I have written the yaml pod and service file which are on my local machine.  However when I ssh into the Kubernetes master it doesn't know how to find files on my local machine nor do I know how to tell it.  Mind you I'm also pretty new to the Linux shell.

I have tried putting the yaml files up in git hub and google drive but this didn't work for me.  Can I push my yaml files into docker hub?  My class didn't go over this because the instructor uses Minikube instead of a full blown VM on a separate host.  So he just typed `kubectl apply -f <filename.yaml>` and it it took the file from his current working directory and pushed it into Kubernetes. So that won't work for me since have to remote in to the server(terminal) first.  Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

> when I ssh into the Kubernetes master it doesn't know how to find files on my local machine nor do I know how to tell it

The prober way to interact with your Kubernetes cluster, is to send your requests to the API-Server. The API Server is a REST API, but it is easiest to use `kubectl` as your client tool.

When you setup your cluster, you should have a "kubeconfig" - this is configuration that your local `kubectl` client should use to authenticate to your cluster.